# Tool for building intelligent agent?

Tags: open-source, artificial-intelligence

Suggest me any open source based platform/IDE/framework/toolkit for developing intelligent agent. I don't have any background in this area, would like to use a tool or any tutorial in building intelligent agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any background at all, I suggest you start with something simple.

I had quite a good experience with [dmangame](http://okayzed.github.com/dmangame/introduction.html), a simple Python engine where you can script the behaviour of agents.

The good point is that the installation is very simple, you know where to code your Python scripts for AI, there is a nice API for it. And you've got a nice graphical interface to see directly what you code.

Edit : By the way, look at this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175997/intelligent-agents-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

[Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) is probably the most comprehensive open source AI toolkit. It's positioned as a tool for "data mining" but don't let that put you of - it's a general toolset for machine learning  which is exactly what you need if you want to build an intelligent agent.

You can use any IDE you like with it (it's Java based so that gives you a range of great open source IDEs such as Eclipse or Netbeans, but you can also call the Weka libraries from other languages if you like).

It also has some of its own tools build it (for visualisation and exploring data sets etc.)

Comment: It truly is one of the best machine learning toolkit available. However, it is not designed for intelligent agents. Classification/Regression/Clustering is nice and all, but these are not the tools needed for this task. For a beginner, HFSM (Hierarchical Finite State Machine) are much more appropriate.

Comment: @Fezvez - hmmm I agree that HFSMs are a great tool though at some point the decisions that drive the state transitions have to depend on analysing some kind of complex input. At that point, you absolutely need the Weka-type tools. To create an intelligent agent, one might implement a simple state machine and let Weka learn the right transition probabilities / state change criteria for different inputs.